# UTF-16 error, how to solve the unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: c#, utf-16

> This program is a translator program that takes some symbols and converts them to normal letters.
>   The problem is, when I try to put some symbols like: allAlphabets.Add("[]/[]"); or:  allAlphabets.Add("//"); , i get an error about the UTF-16

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string input = ""; // string input
        List<string> allAlphabets = new List<string>(); // storing to a list
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] word = input.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (word[i]) // switch casce
            {
           normal letters
                case 'm':
                    allAlphabets.Add("[]\/[]"); // represents text as a sequence of utf-16 code units 
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    allAlphabets.Add("[]\[]"); // represents text as a sequence of utf-16 code units
                case 'v':
                    allAlphabets.Add("\/"); // represents text as a sequence of utf-16 code units
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    allAlphabets.Add("\/\/"); // represents text as a sequence of utf-16 code units

             }
          }
       }
    }
```

> Does someone know a way of encoding the unrecognized escape sequence?
>   Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [verbatim identifier](http://@%20(C#%20Reference)) (`@`)

> To indicate that a string literal is to be interpreted verbatim. The `@`
>   character in this instance defines a verbatim string literal. Simple
>   escape sequences (such as `"\\"` for a backslash), hexadecimal escape
>   sequences (such as `"\x0041"` for an uppercase A), and Unicode escape
>   sequences (such as `"\u0041"` for an uppercase A) are interpreted
>   literally. Only a quote escape sequence (`""`) is not interpreted
>   literally; it produces a single quotation mark. Additionally, in case
>   of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences (`{{` and `}}`)
>   are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters.

```
allAlphabets.Add(@"[]\/[]");
```

or escape the backslash

```
allAlphabets.Add("[]\\/[]")
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences)
- [Regular and Verbatim String Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals)
- [String Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences)